# How to play Google Drive video (in Cloud) like stream without download by using a application (in Local)?

Tags: video, cloud, media

Is there a application that is able to access videos in Google Drive cloud and play them like local videos without download them?

Comment: Are you not able to do this using a web browser by going to https://drive.google.com ?

Comment: @mchid  In a browser you will still download video data to the local machine. It just wont be saved .. or it might be savet in some cache / temporary file.

Comment: @SorenA Thanks, I already know this but I think the OP might be talking about having to save the entire video as a downloaded file before watching. You don't have to save the file to watch a video using google drive from a web browser. It is only temporary through the web browser like a youtube video.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, It works.

I used `google-drive-ocamlfuse` and  `gnome-mpv`.

Using `google-drive-ocamlfuse`, I mounted Google Drive cloud to a local folder.

Using `gnome-mpv`, I play videos successfully. I also tried `vlc`, `chromium-browser`. They could work, but late.

Answer (score 0):

No. To play a video it has to be downloaded to the local machine. Even when you stream all data are send to your machine .. it might not be saved, or just be saved temporarily .. but it has to be on the machine for you to view it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this firefox extension [vdhcoapp-bin](https://www.downloadhelper.net/install-coapp?browser=firefox). It actually has native Linux clients, a .deb or .rpm file and for Arch users its there on the aur